# Como unir várias listas em uma matriz

Tags: python

Como seria uma maneira de mesclar duas listas em uma matriz, onde cada coluna da matriz representa uma dessas listas.

Exemplo:

```
a = ["Laranja", "Maçã", "Uva"]
b = [40, 50, 2, 45, 56]
```

Resultado esperado:

```
x = (["Laranja", 40], ["Maça", 50], ["Uva", 2], ["", 45], ["", 56])
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar o `zip_longest` da biblioteca `itertools`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

a = ["Laranja", "Maçã", "Uva"]
b = [40, 50, 2, 45, 56]

x = list(zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=''))
```

Se você estiver utilizando Python2, substitua `zip_longest` por `izip_longest`.

Answer (score 2):

Existe um comando chamado zip que é da biblioteca nativa do Python, ele recebe como argumento o nome da variável que armazena as listas. Por exemplo:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

a = ["Laranja", "Maçã", "Uva"]
b = [40, 50, 2, 45, 56]

x = zip(a, b)
```

O único problema é que como a lista tem quantidade de valores diferenciados ele só dará append até o indice que todas as listas tem em comum

Answer (score -1):

```
a = ['Laranja', 'Maçã', 'Uva', 'Melancia', 'Limão']
b = [40, 50, 2, 45, 56, 12, 21, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12]

x = []

for i in zip(a, b):
    x.append(i)

print(x)#irá aparecer como uma lista com tupla dentro, mas se quiseres como um dicionario

y = dict(x)#desta forma irá aparecer como um dicionario
print(y)
```